# Why do I get KeyError while reading data with get request?

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, httprequest, get-request

I am trying this simple code to read data from a website, but it gives me `KeyError['p']`:

```
for i in range(25200):

    time.sleep(1)
    with requests.Session() as s:
               data = {'current' : 'afghan_usd' }
               r = s.get('http://call5.tgju.org/ajax.json?2019061716-20190617171520-I4OJ3OcWf4gtpzr3JNC5', json = data ).json()
               #print(r)
    for key, value in r["current"].items():
        last_prices = (r[key]['p'])
        z.append(last_prices)
        mid.append(mean(z))
```

The given `r` is like this:

```
{'current': {'afghan_usd': {'p': '154530', 'h': '157260', 'l':
 '154530', 'd': '3640', 'dp': 2.36, 'dt': 'low', 't': '۱۷:۲۷:۰۳',
 't_en': '17:27:03', 't-g': '۱۷:۲۷:۰۳', 'ts': '2019-06-17 17:27:03'}}
```

And you can see the full content of response(`r` ) here: https://github.com/rezaee/coursera-test/issues/1

EDIT:

I edited my code like this:

```
for i in range(25200):

    time.sleep(1)
    with requests.Session() as s:
               data = {'current' : 'afghan_usd' }#code}
               r = s.get('http://call5.tgju.org/ajax.json?2019061716-20190617171520-I4OJ3OcWf4gtpzr3JNC5', json = data ).json()
               #print(r)

    for key, value in r["current"]["afghan_usd"].items():
        last_prices = float(value.replace("," , ""))
        z.append(last_prices)
        mid.append(mean(z))
```

But I get this new error:

> AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: There is something missing here: `'current': , 'afghan_usd'`, between comma and colon. Are you sure of your output?

Comment: @olinox14: Sorry, I fixed it. The real output has many other object's that I wanted to only copy the specific one.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're trying to loop over `r["current"]`:

```py
for key, value in r["current"].items():
    # for first iteration:
    # key is afghan_usd
    # value is {'p': ....}
    try:
        price = value["p"]
    except TypeError:  # value is a string
        price = value
    last_prices = float(price.replace(',', ''))
    z.append(last_prices)
    mid.append(mean(z))
```

Comment: Thank you for help. I am trying to run your code. For your question, because I am trying to plot my chart online. So I use `mean()` inside the loop.

Comment: I get this error with your code: `TypeError: can't convert type 'str' to numerator/denominator`

Comment: You haven't posted the full response, but in case `p` value is always an integer, you can write `last_prices = int(value['p'])`

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '126,693'

Comment: This is the good answer. And the `ValueError` comes from the fact you are trying to get the `mean` of strings. Consider changing `last_prices = (value['p'])` by `last_prices = float(value['p'])`

Comment: You haven't posted an example with comma separated strings. Anyway, try `last_prices = int(value['p'].replace(',', ''))`

Comment: It says `TypeError: string indices must be integers
` . See the edit part I added to my question

Comment: You'd have to share the full JSON response in order for us to understand the context of the errors.

Comment: Do you know a place to upload text file?  It's a very big string

Comment: Dear @AdamGold: I uploaded the full responce(content of `r`) here: https://github.com/rezaee/coursera-test/issues/1

Comment: When you use `last_prices = float(value['p'].replace(',', ''))`, add `print(value)` and post the last printed line before the error.

Comment: Value is a string with the content`133,300`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195074/discussion-between-adamgold-and-user145959).

Answer (score 1):

A few suggestions:

Move this before the loop

```
with requests.Session() as s:
```

And before that line have

```
data = {'current' : 'afghan_usd' }
```

Then have your loop and double check that you are accessing at the right level as it looks like this:

```
last_prices = (r[key]['p'])
```

is producing an object rather than a simple datatype.

Be sure to indent this properly within your code as it should be within the outer loop

```
for key, value in r.items():
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through `r.items()` and retrieving "p" from each each. The item "current" doesn't have an entry "p".

Comment: How should I fix it? I am confused.

Comment: you could try `last_prices = r['key'].get('p')` and then check if there is a value for `last_prices` as in, `if last_prices: z.append(last_prices)`

Comment: Again `
KeyError: 'key' `

Comment: That's wrong: he is iterating over `r["current"].items()`, not `r.items()`

Comment: @olinox14 OP has edited the question several times. The original was r.items()

Comment: @Karl Ah ok, sorry then... Maybe you should delete this answer?